# Android how to create counter from service?

Tags: android, xml, android-layout, android-tablayout

i am trying to make a point meter like following picture.i searched for it a lot but couldn't find any help.
[image]

any help or hint will be appreciated. thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That looks like a car odometer to me, so I think that if you search for "android odometer" you will have more luck. Here are two links to get you started:

A [GitHub project](https://github.com/obeunda/Odometer/blob/master/src/com/wandapp/odometer/views/OdometerSpinner.java) and a [tutorial](http://kevindion.com/2010/12/android-odometer-ui-tutorial-part-1/).